# How to create a new database and collection using pymongo?

Tags: windows, database, mongodb

I want to create a database and collection using python script so that I used pymongo driver. But I am unable to create database.

Steps I followed:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
con = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = con.testdb
```

After this commands when I checked in mongoshell the db "testdb" is not created.

Can I use paramiko to interact with mongo shell ?

python version : 2.7

Comment: MongoDB creates new databases implicitly upon their first use, so you need to insert at least one document into a collection in `testdb` in order to see the database created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

It states

```
An important note about collections (and databases) in MongoDB is that 
they are created lazily - none of the above commands have actually 
performed any operations on the MongoDB server. **Collections and 
databases are created when the first document is inserted into them.**
```